# how to use the case statement along with || operator in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help to explain the meaning of below sql statement?

```
FROM
  (
    CSA.X_INITIATED_BY_PSID
   ||
    CASE
      WHEN (SELECT USER_FULLNAME
        FROM TABLE_NAME
        WHERE USER_PSID = CSA.X_INITIATED_BY_PSID) IS NULL
      THEN \' - NA\'
      ELSE \' - \'
        ||
        (SELECT USER_FULLNAME
        FROM TABLE_NAME
        WHERE USER_PSID = CSA.X_INITIATED_BY_PSID
        )
    END INTITATED_BY
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the structure of your tables, so I have used a minimal example:

```
SELECT dummy || ' ' || 
       CASE  (SELECT count(*) FROM dual) 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'huh?' 
        END AS x
  FROM dual;

X one
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `FROM` clause? I don't think so.

If you asked what it does, then: it concatenates `CSA.X_INITIATED_BY_PSID` column value with

- `table_name.user_fullname` if there's a row whose `USER_PSID` is equal to previously mentioned `X_INITIATED_BY_PSID`
- `NA` if there's no such row

For example:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  csa (x_initiated_by_psid) as
  4    (select 1 from dual union all
  5     select 2 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_name (user_psid, user_fullname) as
  8    (select 1, 'Little' from dual
  9    )
 10  -- your query
 11  select c.x_initiated_by_psid ||' - '||
 12    case when (select t.user_fullname from table_name t
 13               where t.user_psid = c.x_initiated_by_psid
 14              ) is null then 'NA'
 15         else
 16              (select t.user_fullname from table_name t
 17               where t.user_psid = c.x_initiated_by_psid
 18              )
 19    end result
 20  from csa c;

RESULT
-------------------------------------------------
1 - Little
2 - NA

SQL>
```

---

Though, that's probably overcomplicated solution as outer join does the same with less effort:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  csa (x_initiated_by_psid) as
  4    (select 1 from dual union all
  5     select 2 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_name (user_psid, user_fullname) as
  8    (select 1, 'Little' from dual
  9    )
 10  -- your query
 11  select c.x_initiated_by_psid ||' - '|| nvl(t.user_fullname, 'NA') result
 12  from csa c left join table_name t on t.user_psid = c.x_initiated_by_psid;

RESULT
-------------------------------------------------
1 - Little
2 - NA

SQL>
```